How to implement Shiro2CryptFormat in Shiro 2
Does anyone has the solution how to implement Shiro2CryptFormat in encrypting? Below codes are from V 1. I just upgraded from Shiro V 1 to 2.0.1. And prefers to use the new Argon2. When changing from Shiro1CryptFormat to Shiro2CryptFormat, it reported as java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Shiro2CryptFormat.
final DefaultPasswordService dfPS = new DefaultPasswordService();
((DefaultHashService) dfPS.getHashService()).setDefaultAlgorithmName(SHA_256); 
dfPS.setHashFormat(new Shiro1CryptFormat()); 
return dfPS.encryptPassword(plaintextPWD));


Can you set up a full example? I will gladly take a look at it.
